# Not able to open android studios after installation even after configuring JDK path in system properties

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio is not opening up and gives no further action.
Configured JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME in the system properties.
Still facing the same issue

[image]

Comment: Which OS you're using? If windows goto `C:\Users\<your_name>\.android`  and delete `.android` directory and restart the Android Studio.

Comment: its windows.
i deleted but still same